# What does $\max_{i=1}^k (f_i(x) - q_i)$ mean? Is it a sum?

Tags: maxima-minima

What does $\max_{i=1}^k (f_i(x) - q_i)$ mean?

Is it a sum?

This is the Chebyshev achievement function. And it's taken in "$L^{\infty}$ sense".

The optimization problem related to this is written:

$$\min_{x \in S}\max_{i=1}^k (f_i(x) - q_i) $$

Does this mean that one finds first index $i$ or $x$?

Comment: The context might give more information. At first glance, this is the maximum of $f_1(x)-q_1, \dots, f_k(x)-q_k$ where $x$ is fixed and the $f_i$ taking values in an ordered set.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, I think it's the same as "sup-norm". However, I also put an extra question w.r.t. how to read this when in an minimization problem.